# How to reduce the amount of white space appearing until next set of images gets loaded as user scrolls down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide, fade

I've written some jQuery code and manipulated some CSS code to hide the images contained in `<div>` tags when the page loads for the first time or if user refreshes the page.
If you go to the following URL
**http://example.com**

you will come to know about what I've done.

When you visits this page for the first time, as you scroll down the page you will see the set of images(one/two images in one row ) appearing.

But if you closely observe this functionality you will find that the amount of white space appearing as I scroll down the page until the next set of images appear is too much.

You will experience this "Too Much Blank Space" issue better on a tablet or phone.

I want to reduce this space to 5% of the current white space appearing. I tried many tricks with my code but still no success.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

For your reference I'm putting below the code I've written :

HTML code is :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" id="heading">
 <h3 align="center">Current Rebates</h3>
        <div  class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
        <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
           <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 hideme">
         <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
           <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
         <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
          <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
     <div class="row ">
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/5.jpg"/>
         <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/6.jpg"/>
          <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/7.jpg"/>
          <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/8.jpg"/>
          <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
        <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/6.jpg"/>
          <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
         <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 hideme">
        <img src="img/7.jpg"/>
         <table id="table-transform">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="span6"> <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
           <p>Exp. Date 12th sep, Rebate Count- 20 </p></td>
        <td class=""> <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS Code is  :

```
<style>
    .hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-absolute {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}
}
.navbar-absolute + div {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
body { padding-top: 58px; }
    </style>
```

jQuery code is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            //alert(bottom_of_object);
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},300);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue. If you need any other information about the issue I'm facing please do let me know. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Waiting for your precious replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by basic math. You need to reduce the space to 5% out of your current space. So you reduce 95% of the original value:

`if( bottom_of_window > (bottom_of_object - (bottom_of_object * 0.95 )){`

Although this results in the images showing [too soon](http://jsfiddle.net/6g4r6ecv/embedded/result/)

I would recommend you reduce it to 20% like in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6g4r6ecv/1/embedded/result/)